# Can I request a client certificate from Active Directory CA with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509

I'd like to automate the task of requesting client certificates from the CA attached to our Active Directory. Currently, I use certmgr and click "Request New Certificate" from the menu and do several other selections, including selecting an appropriate policy.

Surely, Powershell can help me with this, as I already use it to get rid of old certificates. Is there a module which can be used for this or does Powershell 3 cover this out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0):

I think [certreq](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc725793.aspx) could be what you are looking for.

> Certreq can be used to request certificates from a certification authority (CA), to retrieve a response to a previous request from a CA, to create a new request from an .inf file, to accept and install a response to a request, to construct a cross-certification or qualified subordination request from an existing CA certificate or request, and to sign a cross-certification or qualified subordination request.

Then there is another useful utility when dealing with certificates in windows - [certutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732443.aspx)